Proving $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|=O(\log t)$ uniformly for $1\le\sigma\le 2$ and $t\ge 10$

Prove that $|\zeta(\sigma+it)|=O(\log t)$ uniformly for $1\le\sigma\le 2$ and $t\ge 10$.

The solution given by my lecturer is as follows. Recall the approximate formula for zeta, given by $$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^s}+\frac{N^{1-s}}{s-1}-s\int_N^{\infty}\frac{\{t\}}{t^{s+1}}dt$$ for any integer $N>0$ and $\textrm{Re}(s)>0$. Substituting $s=\sigma+it$ into this formula, we have three terms which are (respectively) bounded above by $O(\log N), O(1)$ and $O(t)\int_N^{\infty}\frac{\{t\}}{t^{\sigma+1}}dt\ll t\int_N^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^2}dt=O(t/N)$.
I find this confusing - it makes sense to me that we should use the approximate formula here, but I don't understand the bounds we have here. For instance, to bound the first term, we could do an integral comparison, such as $$\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{1}{n^s}\sim\int_1^N\frac{1}{x^s}dx=\left[\frac{x^{1-s}}{1-s}\right]^{N}_1=\frac{N^{1-s}-1}{1-s},$$ and I don't see how this is $O(\log N)$.
Are we supposed to write $s=\sigma+it$ here or does it not matter? If we write $s=\sigma+it$ we would have this bound as $$\frac{N^{1-\sigma-it}-1}{1-\sigma-it}$$ but it isn't clear to me how we would get the required bound here. As for the middle term, I accept this is $O(1)$. For the last term, the presence of $t$ in the bound confuses me.

Note that the integral comparison works only for real $s$ so even if for $s=1$ you have $t \ge 10$ indeed, you cannot use it that way - what you do is you bound the first term by absolute values so get $\sum_{1 \le k \le N}\frac{1}{N^{\sigma}}$ and then use the harmonic sum bound for $\sigma=1$ to get $O(\log N)$ as clearly that is best possible (the maximal sum is when $\sigma=1$)
For the third term, the way is written is confusing as it should be $$s\int_N^{\infty}\frac{\{u\}}{u^{s+1}}du=O(|s|\int_N^{\infty}\frac{1}{u^{\sigma+1}}du)=O(|s|/N^{\sigma})$$ and again since $1 \le \sigma \le 2$ and $s=\sigma+it$ this becomes $O(t/N)$
So overall you get $O(\log N)+O(1)+O(t/N)$ and choosing $N=t$ gives you indeed $O(\log t)$
Note that the best choice $t=N \log N$ (so $N \approx t/\log t$) which equalizes the two biggest error terms doesn't give you better since $\log (t/\log t) \sim \log t$ anyway.

Thanks! I think I understand now.

Happy to be of help
